# What is the correct way to sign android app for sharing in different stores?

Tags: android, signing

When I want to upload android APK file to Google play, google asks me if I want to sign application using google app signing key or not? I have uploaded the APK on different stores and I want users to be notified for app updates from any store.

Should I skip google signing step or it is not related to release updates?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The way Android (and Google Play) work by default is that users will only get updates from Google Play if they installed from Google Play. Other well behaved app stores will probably have the same behaviour. Amazon App store will always sign with their own certificate as far as I can see, so the app will never have the same certificate. So what you want won't happen.

If I were you I'd just use Google Play app signing. It protects you if you ever lose your key, have a former employee compromise it, and a large number of other problems that affect developers every year.

Comment: What if I skip this step (skip is available when I want upload apk)? Does it works parallel to other stores?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. If you don't understand this, then I'd let Google manage your key for you. Chances are if you don't understand this stuff you'll make a mistake otherwise.